# How do I clear / set the password field emptyText onfocus / onblur?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have password and confirm password fields that I want to display `*********` in until the field gets focus.

```
var passwordFields = {
    layout: "vbox",
    border: 0,
    defaults: {
        xtype: "textfield",
        inputType: "password",
        labelAlign: "top",
        emptyText: "********",
        validateOnChange: false
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: "Password",
        name: "pass",
        allowBlank : false,
        itemId: "pass"
    }, {
        fieldLabel: "Confirm Password",
        name: "pass-cfrm",
        allowBlank: false,
        initialPassField: "pass"
    }]
};
```

do I need to add an `onfocus` handler in order to make the emptyText go away when the field is in focus but the user hasn't typed anything or is there an easier way that I'm missing?

**edit:**

I added the following code to the controller which sets the value as needed depending on a flag but was hoping that the default behavior of the emptyText would be that it disappears onfocus and reappears after onblur if the field is empty...

```
var field = this.getPassField();
field.emptyText = "••••••••";
field.applyEmptyText();
```

Comment: hmm, interesting question +1. My last emptyText runs in ExtJS 3.4 and there it vanish as soon as the field get focus.

Comment: I've only ever used extjs 4+ thanks for commenting

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved though the feature

```
inputType:'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a missing feature. If you look at the comments to the inputType docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-inputType you'll see that someone already discovered that. 
However I am using emptyText on other field types and they work just fine.

Comment: how can i look comments to the inputType docs? i am not seeing any comments or link to comments etc.

Comment: Follow the link and click 'View 1 comment' link

Comment: Thanks for commenting :) ...and validating that I am not crazy!